# Linking errors while exporting std::vector from dll

Tags: c++, stl, linker, dllimport, dllexport

I have a dll (`my_library.dll`) that exports a struct using __`declspec(dllexport)`. Since this struct contains an `std::vector<std::wstring> member`, I've also exported functions for it like so:

```
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::allocator<std::wstring>;
template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<std::wstring>;
```

Please note that I've defined macros such that dll exports above struct and vector when compiling and they are imported (via `__declspec(dllimport))` when the dll is being used by another application.
The above dll builds fine.

Now this my_library.dll (and the corresponding `my_library.lib`) is linked to an exe (`my_exe.exe`). This exe has a .cpp file (`exe_source.cpp`) that defines a `global std::vector<std::wstring>` variable. This source file compiles fine.
However when building this exe, I get the following error:

> my_library.lib(my_library.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall
>   std::vector,class std::allocator
>
> > ,class std::allocator,class std::allocator
> >
> > > > ::~vector,class std::allocator
> > > >         ,class std::allocator,class std::allocator
> > > >         (void)" (??1?$vector@V?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@GU?$char_traits@G@std@@V?$allocator@G@2@@std@@@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in exe_source.obj

What I suspect is that the my_library.dll has all `std::vector<std::wstring>` functions defined and exported, and using the global `std::vector<std::wstring>` variable in the `exe_source.cpp` is also resulting in definition of many `std::vector<std::wstring>` functions, leading to linker complaining that multiple definitions of such functions are found.

Am I understanding the error correctly?

And how to fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Even if you got this to link, it isn't a good idea to export C++ classes where you really have no control over their internal implementations.  If your app is compiled with different compiler options, different compiler version, etc.  that `vector` isn't going to be the same `vector` the DLL is using.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the suggestion. However, I think that vectors can be imported correctly, as suggested by the Microsoft article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958.

Comment: Whether it is correct or not, it isn't a good idea or a habit to get into.  As the answer from @MrC64 states, it is highly brittle design choice.

Comment: You are storing up huge amounts of trouble for the future. Ignore the advice you have been given at your peril.

Comment: I want to clarify that I encourage the OP to follow better design choices (as already written in my answer), like having a DLL exporting a **pure C interface** (C++ is fine _inside_ the implementation of the DLL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, having STL classes at DLL interfaces is a **highly constraining** design choice: in fact, both the DLL and the other modules using it (e.g. the EXE built by your DLL clients) must be built with the *same* C++ compiler version and linking to the *same* flavor of the CRT DLL.

Better design choices would be exporting a DLL with a **pure C interface** (the *implementation* can use C++, but you should flatten the public API to make it C), or use a *COM-like* approach of exporting **C++ abstract interfaces**, as suggested in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL).

Assuming you are aware of that, you should be able to remove the lines:

> ```
> template class __declspec(dllexport) std::allocator<std::wstring>;
> template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<std::wstring>;
> ```

and just export the structure hosting your STL data members, for example:

**MyLib.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MYLIB_API
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MYLIB_API MyLib_Data
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> Strings;
    // ... other stuff ...
};
```

**MyLib.cpp**

```
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include "MyLib.h"

// ... Implementation code ...
```

Note that you may receive a warning C4251, something like:

> ```
> 'MyLib_Data::Strings' : class 'std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
> needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'MyLib_Data'
> ```

but you may ignore it.

Comment: But then will I be able to use the vector in my_exe.exe? Although I don't change it, I do use this vector in my_exe.exe. **Update**: not using the template class statements results in unresolved externals errors where I iterate the vector member in the exe.

Comment: Assuming your exe is built with the same VC++ compiler version and links with the same flavor of the CRT, yes. Just try it.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong: I tried a simple repro with the above code snippet and an EXE iterating through the vector via a range-based for, and the strings are displayed correctly. (Of course, make sure to link your EXE with the .lib file generated by the linker and associated to your DLL.)

Comment: I have a getter function member in the struct that returns this vector, I use this in the exe and assign it to a local vector variable and use iterator to iterate the vector.

Comment: @AarCee: Just tried adding a simple getter and it works fine as well.

Comment: Yes I must have been doing something different before. It does compile, thanks. However, what would be a good way to do this, given that I need to access the vector variable from the struct in the exe? Do you suggest adding member functions to the struct that work on the vector in the dll itself, so external apps will just use those vector interface kind of functions to work on the vector? Seems like a hacky way, given that I'll be writing functions that wrap vector functionality.

Comment: @AarCee: The real hacky way to me seems to force your DLL clients to use the _same_ version of VC++ and dynamically link to the _same_ flavor of the CRT to use your DLL in their production environment. I already suggested better design choices in my answer (for example: use a C-like interface, hiding the STL data members inside the DLL implementation). Or you could just distribute a **header-only** C++ template library with STL classes, if that does make sense for your particular needs.

Comment: I was just confirming that itself in my previous comment. I'll have to add interface-like functions for doing operations on the vector?

Comment: @AarCee: That is an option.

Comment: So for example to iterate through the vector, I'll have to add an iterator type interface for it, i.e. get_first_element(), get_next_element(), get_size(), etc. I'm a little surprised that this is the way to do a thing like this. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AarCee: As an alternative, you could distribute just a C++ header-only library (like [CImg does](http://cimg.eu/)), but this would expose the whole implementation (you may or may not want that). You're welcome.